# ¿Como puedo guardar un número digitado por el usuario para compararlo después con otro ingresado en java?

Tags: java, texto

Básicamente el problema me pide que cuando el usuario ingresa un numero y este es mayor al anterior entonces al contador le sumas uno y en una cadena de texto guardas "+1". todo lo contrario en el caso que sea menor que el numero anteriormente.

No se como puedo realizar esta comparación entre los números que vaya ingresando el usuario.

Esto es lo que llevo de código, mas o menos realiza las funciones que pide el problema, pero falta la comparación, como dice en el titulo, no se si es necesario guardar cada numero en un acumulador. El problema lo pide dentro del método Main.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
  public static void main (String args[]){

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    double num = 0.0; 
    int contador = 0;
    String cadena = " " ;
    double elem;

    for(num = scan.nextDouble();num <=-1 || num >= 1; num = scan.nextDouble()){   
       if(num >= elem ){
         contador = contador + 1;
         cadena = cadena + "\n+1";
       }    
       if (num <elem){
           contador = contador - 1;
           cadena = cadena + "\n-1";
       }
    }
    System.out.println(cadena);
    System.out.println("contador:"+" "+contador);
  }  
}
```

Si alguien  me podría ayudar con esto muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

**RESPUESTA RAPIDA**

1. Pides el numero al usuario
2. Como es el primero no se puede comparar con el anterior (+1)
3. Guardar ese primer numero en una variable X (elem)
4. Segunda ronda **Pides el numero al usuario**
5. Comparas con el numero que guardaste ene el paso 3 (elem)

Pd: Dudo el que el for como lo tienes funcione correctamente, No puedes compara **elem** en el if si no tiene un valor.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main (String args[]){

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        double num = 0.0;
        int contador = 0;
        String cadena = " " ;
        double elem =0;//Numero ingresado anterior anterior
        int cant = 5;

        for (int i = 0; i < cant; i++) {
            num = scan.nextDouble();
            if (num>= elem){
                contador = contador + 1;
                cadena = cadena + "\n+1";
            }else{
                contador = contador - 1;
                cadena = cadena + "\n-1";
            }
            //Guardamos el numero ingresado para luego comparar
            elem = num;

        }

//        for(num = scan.nextDouble();num <=-1 || num >= 1; num = scan.nextDouble()){
//            if(num >= elem ){
//                contador = contador + 1;
//                cadena = cadena + "\n+1";
//            }
//            if (num <elem){
//                contador = contador - 1;
//                cadena = cadena + "\n-1";
//            }
//        }
        System.out.println(cadena);
        System.out.println("contador:"+" "+contador);
    }
}
```